# Accessing multi-dimensional array with conditions in R

Tags: arrays, r, statistics

I am currently stuck on this question and I need help.

According to the question, I created a multi-dimensional array (AR) from a vector (baz).

Here is the code for the vector *baz*:

```
boo <- c(3,6,7,9,6,3,6,6,7,1,9,1)
```

After creating baz, the question then instructed me to "fill a 2x2x3 array with the vector created"

Here is my code for creating the array *AR*:

```
AR <- array (data = baz, dim =c(2,2,3))
```

Output in R studio:

[image: Output in R studio]

The next set of instructions goes like this -

Examine the array for the following entries:

(i) Those less than or equal to 6 divided by 2, plus 4

(ii) Those less than or equal to 6 divided by 2, plus 4, after increasing every element in the array by 2

May I know how do I access elements in a multi-dimensional array with a condition and add an increment of 2 (for part ii) according to this question? Thank you.

Comment: Hard to know exactly what you mean by i and ii.`6/2 + 4 = 7`? But you need to learn enough about R to know that many operations including arithmetic and logical operations are vectorized. They are covered on manual pages including `?logical`, `?Arithmetic`. You may find `?which` useful, especially the `arr.ind=` argument. Try `AR + 2` to see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if what you want is to access each element of each array at a time you can use this:

```
for(i in 1:length(AR)){ 
     if(AR[i] >= 6){ #your condition
       # Your operation add an increment of 2, for egg 
       # AR[i] <- AR[i] + 2    

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot! :) I have some other questions regarding R as well, is it convenient to get your email?

Comment: @plzhelp No problem, we're here to help. winiciuss15@gmail.com